# cordova serving images with angular ng-src from a folder internal to an android device

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

in an ng-repeat directive, i need to serve images from a folder internal to the target device, allowing a certain easiness for updates.

I know only two methods to load images and both are obviusly not working:

```
<cart-item ng-repeat="item in cart.items">
   <img ng-src="http://myserver/project/images/{{item.name}}.jpeg" alt="">
      <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
</cart-item>  // but with this of course everytime i'm downloading images from server
```

or

```
<cart-item ng-repeat="item in cart.items">
   <img ng-src="images/{{item.name}}.jpeg" alt="">
      <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
</cart-item>  // and with this all images are compiled inside apk. (must recompile      everytime i want to change a single image??)
```

so.. how to obtain something like :

```
<img ng-src="sdcardonandroid/mydreamfolder/{{item.name}}.jpeg" alt="">
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For both, you are taking src="images/{{image.name}}" which will not work, as {{item.name}} will work with the angular. Where as, in the second one ng-src no need to give the path as images/.. just specify the {{item.name}}, it will take the data automatically and store the image in the complete path format in file that will make you easy

Comment: In the ng-src also we can declare the path of the folder as {{"...path....."+ item.name}} or {{",,,,,path.."+ item.imagename}}. And no need to declare .jpeg specifically as it come from image file name. Better if you provide me some sample or example of your code so that i can help you @RaduD